# woocommerce how to list products in cart according to category?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using woocommerce with wordpress. I need to show products in cart by category.for ex. if user select a product from category1 and add to cart then add product in cart from category2 and again add any other product from category1.Then i need to products of category1 and then category 2.I need to show products in this way in cart.I am trying to changing the code in cart.php file.

Cart

```
 Category1

 product name   category       qty    price
 aaa           category1      2      50
 bbb               category1      1       10
```

Category2

```
product name   category       qty    price
test1          category2      2      40
test2          category2      1      10     

$taxonomies = get_terms( array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product-cat',
            'hide_empty' => false,
        ) );

        foreach ( $taxonomies as $_tax ) 
        {
             $allfactories[] = $_tax->name;
        }




        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {

            //print_r($cart_item);

            $cart_cat = $cart_item['wdm_user_custom_data_value'];

            $terms = wp_get_object_terms($cart_item['product_id'], 'product-cat');
            foreach ($terms as $term) {
               $product_cat = $term->name;
               $factory[]  = $term->name;
            }

            if($product_cat==$cart_cat)
            {

            $_product     = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
            $product_id   = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product_id', $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

            }

        }
```

Comment: can anyone suggest?